# How could RDF vocabularies specify property categories (from "URLs in Data Primer")?

Tags: url, rdf, ontology, vocabulary, rdfs

The W3C [TAG](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/) published the Working Draft [**URLs in Data Primer**](http://www.w3.org/TR/urls-in-data/) last month. It specifies a solution for the [httpRange-14 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669).

Now vocabularies should specify [categories](http://www.w3.org/TR/urls-in-data/#property-categories) for their properties, i.e. if a property applies to the document or to an entity described by the document.

**How should/could RDF vocabularies specify the categories for properties *today*?**

It says that metaformats (→ RDF) [should specify a default category](http://www.w3.org/TR/urls-in-data/#specifying-metaformats) for properties and schema languages (→ RDFS) "[should include mechanisms for indicating the category of a property](http://www.w3.org/TR/urls-in-data/#specifying-schema-languages)". But I guess it will take some time until those specifications are updated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I think that there is no such standardised method today, because right now you still need to differ between a thing and a document that holds a description of the thing. However, you may specify/create an [owl:AnnotationProperty](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Annotation_Properties) to indicate the type of a property in an RDF vocabulary.