# Structured Data > Microdata & Json-LD > Entity IDs > Fragment Identifier

Tags: data-structures, uri, microdata, json-ld, iri

I was wondering if it is better/proper to reference the entities using a fragment identifier format - basically by inserting a hash before the name

`[url] + # + [name]` => `http://example.com/page/#webPage`

**EDIT:**

Following a kind answer from the ever-generous and great @Unor, I have added this edit to try confine the scope of my query and clarify the main issue I am getting at. I have also deleted most of the original question (about 95%) which (in hindsight) I feel detracts from:
1. my core question; and
2. the benefit to future readers.

Here is my issue in short:

*Is the practice of manually typing in a hash at the start of microdata's itemid and json-ld's @id values valid?*

Here is my issue expressed in more detail:

*Can I insert a HASH symbol (#) into microdata's itemid values and json-ld's @id values, to create valid resulting URIs with a proper and valid use of a fragment identifier?*

So if this is on a web page:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person" itemid="#joe"></div>
```

Or if this is also on the web page:

```
{"@context":"http://schema.org",
"@type":"Person",
"@id":"#Joe"}
```

I understand they will be read to make a uri like this (assuming relative construction by the consumer as Google's structured data tester tool does):

```
http://www.example.com/page#joe
```

Is that uri:

1. a valid uri; and
2. is it properly using a fragment identifier (HASH)?

Comment: I’m not sure what exactly you refer to with Google’s tool (it should probably be a separate question if it’s important), but I assume you mean that the tool  generates URIs for elements with the `id` attribute? AFAIK it’s not correct to do this (i.e., not something Microdata/RDFa specify), and I have no idea why they are doing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It’s a good practice to allow to retrieve a description about the entity when requesting the URI (see [Cool URIs for the Semantic Web: **1. Be on the Web.**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/NOTE-cooluris-20081203/#semweb)).

By using **Hash URIs**, you get this functionality for free:

- `http://example.com/flower` represents the document about a flower
- `http://example.com/flower#this` represents the flower
- → When retrieving `http://example.com/flower#this`, you get the document *about* it

By using **Slash URIs**, you have to implement a redirect ([with status code 303](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22923076/1591669)) yourself:

- `http://example.com/flower` represents the document about a flower
- `http://example.com/flower/this` represents the flower
- → When retrieving `http://example.com/flower/this`, you get 303-redirected to the URI *about* it ([see an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669))

So without knowing more about your backend, I’d suggest to go with Hash URIs, because it is typically easier to set up.

(I’m not sure what exactly you mean with "webpage entity", but just to make sure: the Hash URI should be for the "real-world object", not for the document.)

---

Edit (for your updated question):

Yes, you can provide the Hash URI in `itemid` and `@id` ([example](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#reverse-properties)) by specifying only the fragment component (starting with a `#`).

So on a document with the URL `http://example.com/foobar`, these four statements generate the same Hash URI (`http://example.com/foobar#this`):

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://voc.example.net/Example" itemid="#this">
</article>

<article itemscope itemtype="http://voc.example.net/Example" itemid="http://example.com/foobar#this">
</article>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://voc.example.net/",
  "@type": "Example",
  "@id": "#this" 
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://voc.example.net/",
  "@type": "Example",
  "@id": "http://example.com/foobar#this" 
}
</script>
```

(And yes, your example URI is valid; here’s [which characters the fragment component may contain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119120/1591669).)

Notes:

- The fragment is case-sensitive, so your `itemid="#joe"` and `"@id":"#Joe"` resolve to different URIs (`j` vs. `J`).
- When not specifying an absolute Hash URI, you have to make sure that the URL of the current document is canonical. For example, the trailing slash matters (`/page/#joe` vs. `/page#joe`); the query component matters (the page `/page?foo=bar` would create the Hash URI `/page?foo=bar#joe`, not `/page#joe`); if the host has `www.` or not matters; the URI scheme matters (`http` vs. `https`); etc.

Comment: Unor to the rescue ... again! I will edit the question to clarify some of the points you identified.

Comment: Hi @unor. I have edited the question.If you are able to update your answer in light of this clarification, I would be very happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: @TBB: I added a section about how to specify Hash URIs in `itemid`/`@id`. Does this answer your updated question, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This answers my question. I have marked your answer as correct. Thank you yet again for your massive contributions here!