# @id vs. URL for linking JSON-LD nodes

Tags: url, uri, schema.org, json-ld

I have defined the publisher `Organization` on the `WebSite` node defined on the home page, and I now want to link to that publisher from articles on other pages. However, I also want to link to the `WebSite` as well, and they naturally share the same `@id` if I follow the advice of using the URL as the `@id`.

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "@id": "http://www.example.com/",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/",
    ...
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/",  <-- duplicated
        "url": "http://www.example.com/"
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "http://www.example.com/news",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/news",
    "isPartOf": {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/"  <-- site or publisher?
    }
    ...
    "publisher": {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/"  <-- site or publisher?
    }
}
```

I assume IDs must be unique to each node, so is there a best practice for uniquifying IDs such as adding a hash?

```json
{
    "@id": "http://www.example.com/#site",
    ...
    "publisher": {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com/#publisher",
    }
}
```

If that works, will processors (Google) load the `@id` to find the rest of the node's properties?

Related to this, is the `url` property found in many node types assumed to be the `@id` if missing? I'm ending up duplicating the full URL of the page as the `@id` and `url` for most nodes. Is that the norm?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### `@id` (JSON-LD)

(and the same goes for `itemid` in Microdata, and `resource` in RDFa)

Each thing should get a different URI, and if multiple nodes are about the same thing, they should ideally reuse this URI. Note that these don’t have to be URLs, and they should often not be used as values for Schema.org’s `url` property (see section below).

Using URI fragments is a common and the most simple way to achieve this. For examples (and other ways), see my answers to these questions:

- [Best practices for adding semantics to a website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669)
- [Concepts for RDFa DRY references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23633409/1591669)
- [RDF 303 redirect clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22923076/1591669)
- [Structured Data > Microdata & Json-LD > Entity IDs > Fragment Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33640258/1591669)
- [How to implement “mainEntityOfPage” to this specific site?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467088/1591669)

For your example case, an organization’s website, the root URL (`http://www.example.com/`) typically "stands for" three things:

- the home page
- the whole website
- the organization

As the home page is the resource that gets retrieved, it should get the URI `http://www.example.com/`. The site and the organization should get their own fragments; it’s up to you to choose which ones, e.g.: `http://www.example.com/#site` for the site, and `http://www.example.com/#organization` for the organization (FWIW, [Apple seems to use `#organization`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633), too.)

- the home page:
  `http://www.example.com/`
- the whole website:
  `http://www.example.com/#site`
- the organization:
  `http://www.example.com/#organization`

(Often only two different things are involved: the document, and the thing described by the document. Then the thing often gets a fragment like `#this`, and in case of persons, `#i`, but this is just a convention.)

> If that works, will processors (Google) load the `@id` to find the rest of the node's properties?

Google doesn’t document if they try to load those URIs.

Note that there is no requirement that these URIs actually point to a document. You could use HTTP URIs that give 404 answers, or you could use a URI scheme that doesn’t allow retrieval of documents to begin with (e.g., `urn`, `tag`, …).

#### `url` (Schema.org)

Schema.org’s [`url`](http://schema.org/url) property should be used for the URLs that lead to pages that can be visited. It’s not intended as a way to provide an ID, so it’s not necessarily the same URI as provided in `@id`.

In your example case, you would probably use the same `url` value for all three things:

- the home page:
  `@id`: `http://www.example.com/`
  `url`: `http://www.example.com/`
- the whole website:
  `@id`: `http://www.example.com/#site`
  `url`: `http://www.example.com/`
- the organization:
  `@id`: `http://www.example.com/#organization`
  `url`: `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: I've implemented this. Do you see any reason to include the `url` property for all these nodes (e.g. Car with a Review on a WebPage as part of a WebSite) when the `@id`s are the same URL with a hash?

Comment: @DavidHarkness: Yes, I would always provide the `url` property if there is a dedicated page for the thing. A consumer that wants to do something with a link would/should use `url`, not `@id`, because `@id` may just be an identifier (not the URL of an existing page), and I wouldn’t expect all consumers to a) check if `@id` points to an existing/relevant page, or even b) look for `@id` at all.

Comment: Let's say in my service page I have a schema about Service and my home page I have a schema about LocalBusiness. I link Service schema to my Local business with id (provider: id: my-domain#local-business). Do I need to put LocalBusiness schema and Service shema under 1 "big" schema so the Internet can understand the link via id? How can I know that my id is unique? Let's say there is a bad person trying to copy my LocalBusiness id and he uses it to refer different things? @unor