# What exactly are pointers in Schema.org and how to use them with JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

The schema.org docs refer sometimes to "pointers". E.g. [`Product` schema](http://schema.org/Product) has the property `isSimilarTo`.

I do understand, that I could use a `Product`or a `Service` directly. E.g.:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "BMW",
  "isSimilarTo": {
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Mercedes Benz"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "price": "100000.00"
  }
}
</script>
```

Is this the only and the correct way using and interpreting the term 'pointer' in this context? For a pointer, I would rather expect some value (an ID or an URL or similar) just pointing to another product or service.

Comment: I removed your last question, as it’s not directly related to the primary question. If you want to provide multiple `Product` items for the `isSimilarTo` property, you can use an array ([see example in my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is correct, and it follows Schema.org’s recommendation for the expected value of the [`isSimilarTo`](http://schema.org/isSimilarTo) property. But Schema.org allows URI values for each property, even for those that don’t explicitly list `URL` as expected value.

So you could also use:

```json
  "isSimilarTo": {
    "@id": "https://example.com/products/mercedes-benz#this"
  },
```

Note that consumers (like Google) don’t necessarily follow these references. You could also use both ways: provide the data (or some of it) on the current page, and refer to the item’s URI:

```json
   "isSimilarTo": {
    "@id": "https://example.com/products/mercedes-benz#this",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Mercedes Benz",
    "url": "https://example.com/products/mercedes-benz"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks @unor. Does the fragment identifier `#this` has any special meaning?

Comment: Again @unor: Could you point me to the part of the docs, where I can find this kind of information. I have difficulties to find the right documentation.

Comment: @Stefan: See "Expected types vs text." under [Expected types, text, and URLs](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected). // About `#this`: it’s a way to differentiate between the thing itself and the page about this thing. "this" has no special meaning, it’s just a convention (could also be "product" or whatever). To read more about this, see [my answer to the question *@id vs. URL for linking JSON-LD nodes*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41099116/1591669).