# Should the url property in WebSite represent the main page or the current page being rendered?

Tags: url, schema.org

I am trying to add Microdata into my site to help search engines understand my content. The [`WebSite`](https://schema.org/WebSite) definition requires a property called [`url`](https://schema.org/url). I am puzzled on which URL I should have here. Should the `url` be the URL to the main page or the current page being rendered?

For example, if I want to create Microdata for `https://example.com/i/12/some-tag`. Would the `url` then be `https://example.com` or the canonical URL (i.e., `https://example.com/i/12/some-tag`)?

Comment: Note that Schema.org does not require any property; the page lists all properties that can be used, but they don’t have to be used. -- A specific consumer, e.g. Google Search, might have certain requirements for certain features they offer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` of the [`WebSite`](https://schema.org/WebSite) should be the website’s homepage.

If you want to provide structured data about the current page, you can use [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) and its `url` property.

```html
<!-- on https://example.com/i/12/some-tag -->

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/i/12/some-tag" />

  <div itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebSite">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/" />
  </div>

</body>
```

For the homepage itself, the `WebSite` and the `WebPage` would have the same `url` value. By giving each item its own URI as identifier (via Microdata’s `itemid` attribute), you can differentiate between these two (and all other) items. [See this answer for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099116/1591669)

Comment: Currently, I have `<html itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebSite">` after adding the info you provided, is that still 
needed?

Comment: @Junior: You should not have more than one `WebSite` item per document. It doesn’t matter on which element you specify it (`html`, `body`, a `div` etc.).

Comment: If you can only have one Website defined per document, how to your refer to multiple websites that your web page is talking about?