# Rich results test detects error "missing field 'id'" while it is present

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

Following [this guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/breadcrumb). I am adding Microdata to my website's breadcrumbs.

When testing my own code, I am getting the error that the field "id" is missing, while it is not from what I can see and understand. Am I missing something here or is it a bug in the test tool of Google?

You can test yourself at https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result with below code.

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Microdata test</title>
      </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb top">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
                                <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="breadcrumb-item">
                                    <a itemid="http://localhost/hikes-and-walks" href="http://localhost/hikes-and-walks" itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>                        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
                                </li>
                                <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="breadcrumb-item">
                                    <a itemid="http://localhost/hikes-and-walks/hikes/bulgaria" href="http://localhost/hikes-and-walks/hikes/bulgaria" itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><span itemprop="name">Bulgaria</span></a>                        <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
                                </li>
                                <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
                                    <span itemprop="name">Aleko hut to Zheleznitsa village</span>
                                    <meta itemprop="position" content="3" />
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

It is giving the error "Missing field 'id'":
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check Structured Data > Microdata & Json-LD > Entity IDs > Fragment Identifier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624382/structured-data-microdata-json-ld-entity-ids-fragment-identifier -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to some internal validations that are hard to grasp. It looks like `itemid` requires a specific URL structure. In this case either relative or absolute URL (protocol+root+tld) work, i.e.changing `"http://localhost"` to `"http://localhost.site"` passes the test. Relative URLs also work.

So, change itemid URL to:

absolute URL:

`itemid="http://localhost.site/hikes-and-walks"`

or relative URL:

`itemid="/hikes-and-walks"`

Also, these (valid) examples won't work:

```
urn:isbn:9780307476463

file:///ada/Analytical%20Engine/README.md   

ftp://file
```

Here's the working code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Microdata test</title>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb top">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
                            <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="breadcrumb-item">
                                <a itemid="http://localhost.site/hikes-and-walks" href="http://localhost/hikes-and-walks" itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>                        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
                            </li>
                            <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="breadcrumb-item">
                                <a itemid="http://localhost.site/hikes-and-walks/hikes/bulgaria" href="http://localhost/hikes-and-walks/hikes/bulgaria" itemprop="item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage"><span itemprop="name">Bulgaria</span></a>                        <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
                            </li>
                            <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
                                <span itemprop="name">Aleko hut to Zheleznitsa village</span>
                                <meta itemprop="position" content="3" />
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```