# Vocabularies compatible with the Dublin Core

Tags: metadata, dublin-core

I try to express the notion of creator of a company in Dublin Core. This needs to be different than the DublinCore:creator that created the record.

For example

`record:Microsoft
creator:Bill Gates
creator:John Doe`

By the first "creator" I mean the creator of the company, the CEO.
By the second "creator" I mean the user that inserted the record into the system.

Not the same "creators", they refer to different things. How do I do this? Is there a vocabulary or concept scheme, compatible with the Dublin Core that I can use? The FOAF is Dublin Core compatible but has nothing similiar to "title" or "job".

Comment: I assume you are using the RDF vocabulary of Dublin Core (instead of the HTML meta tags), correct? And "compatible" would be any other RDF vocabulary? Maybe you could include the actual code you use?

Comment: @unor This is not a code or an RDF, this is just my notes, I gather all the terms I need and then convert it to code. The problem here is semantics , not implementation. I dont want t have two "creators" in the record, because this may confuse others that will read my scheme. If the scheme gets translated in RDF or HTML there will be two "creators" there with no efficient way to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

You want to say something about two different things: 1. the company itself, 2. the record about the company. Therefore you need two resources.

In RDF, you would represent these resources with URIs. For example, you could reuse [DBpedia’s URI that represents the company Microsoft](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microsoft), and an URI under your own control for the record:

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/some-vocabulary/> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microsoft> ex:creator "Bill Gates" .
<http://example.com/records/microsoft> ex:creator "John Doe" .
```

And then you can, for example, say that the record is about the company:

```
<http://example.com/records/microsoft> ex:about <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Microsoft> .
```

Note that it’s important to use the DBpedia URI with `/resource/` instead of `/page`, to which you get redirected. They do this exactly for the same reason: to differentiate between the company and their page about that company.

You can find more details in my related answers:

- [httpRange-14 issue; differentiating between author of a book and author of a page about the book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669)
- [information resource vs. non-information resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22923076/1591669)
- [URIs for Linked Data; differentiating between events and pages about the events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23633409/1591669)

---

You can use any kind of (RDF-based) vocabulary. I don’t think that Dublin Core’s `creator` property is really suitable for cases where a company is created. Instead, you could use Schema.org’s [`founder`](http://schema.org/founder) property, for example.