# What's the meaning of # in rdf:resource

Tags: xml, rdf

It is unclear to me when should I precede URI inside of `rdf:resource` with `#` character. What exactly does it mean? Is it way to use relative URI, or does it have to be used with `rdf:ID` but not with `rdf:about` ?

Could you append examples of wrong and right usage of `#` inside `rdf:resource`?

Answer (score 3):

The `rdf:resource` attribute has a URI as value (= the subject of the triple).

You can use absolute URIs (e.g., `http://example.com/foobar`), or relative URIs (e.g., `/foobar`). If you use `#foo` as value, that would be a [same-document reference](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-4.4).

So if you use `rdf:resource="#foo"` in a document which has the URI `http://example.com/foobar`, you are specifying the URI `http://example.com/foobar#foo`.

---

Note that many authors use the [fragment](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.5) to differentiate the page from the thing it represents. Example:

- `http://example.com/Buksy` could represent the page about you
- `http://example.com/Buksy#i` could represent you

This is known as *hash URI*, which is a possible solution for the [**httpRange-14** issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669).