# Equivalent RDFa markup for RDF+XML snippet

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfa, rdf-xml

I'm currently learning about all things RDF and was wondering what the equivalent RDFa markup would look like for this RDF+XML snippet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"   
    xmlns:dbo="http://dbpedia.org/ontology#" >

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/page/Bavaria">
        <dbo:population>12440000</dbo:population>
        <dbo:capital rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/page/Munich" />
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I've been looking at the documentation, but can't really figure this out.

Comment: You can convert and compare RDF serializations with [RDF Translator online app](http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the HTML is

```html
<p>
  Munich is the capital of Bavaria (population: 12440000).
</p>
```

then you could use

```html
<p prefix="dbo: http://dbpedia.org/ontology#" resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bavaria">
  <span property="dbo:capital" resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Munich">Munich</span> is the capital of Bavaria (population: <span property="dbo:population">12440000</span>).
</p>
```

to get exactly the same RDF as in your RDF/XML example. There are of course many other possible solutions.

You only need to know a few attributes for [RDFa Lite](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-rdfa-lite-20150317/):

- `vocab` for specifying a default vocabulary (which can be used without prefix)
- `prefix` for specifying vocabulary prefixes
- `resource` for identifiers
- `typeof` for types
- `property` for properties

For more complex cases, refer to the ["full" HTML+RDFa spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/).

---

(Note that I used `http://dbpedia.org/resource/…` instead of `http://dbpedia.org/page/…` URIs. [See why.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669))

Comment: Ah, understood. Thanks!
Changing the URI in the RDF+XML example to the /resource/ scheme would make sense as well, right?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, this goes for every RDF serialization. If you use DBpedia’s /page/ URIs, your statements are about the web documents, not about the things these web documents are about.