# Difference between 'page' and 'resource' in DBpedia URLs

Tags: uri, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

When I was digging DBpedia and trying to learn more about Linked Data, I have seen that DBpedia is redirecting from [`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rome`](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rome)
to [`http://dbpedia.org/page/Rome`](http://dbpedia.org/page/Rome).

I wasn't able to find any reason for that and I would like to learn why this is happening.

Comment: `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rome` is the RDF entity while `http://dbpedia.org/page/Rome` is it's representation as HTML. Look at the principles of Linked Data and HTTP 303 see other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/resource/` URI represents the thing.
The `/page/` URI represents the human-readable document about the thing.
The `/data/` URI represents the machine-readable document about the thing.

(This is the HTTP status code 303 approach. [More details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669))

So, if you want to say something about the city/comune Rome, you have to use the `/resource/` URI.